# Disable the ability to check multiple categories

Tags: categories

Is it possible to disable the ability to check multiple categories for an entry in the control panel, only leaving the option to check one category?

Comment: Could you please clean up your question and clarify a little? I think I know what you mean, but it's grammatically awful. http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

If I actually understand you question, no, it's not possible with native EE. You would need to write a custom add-on. However, with something like this:

https://solspace.com/software/expressionengine/primary_category

You can can probably add both of those categories as Primary Categories; and only one should be selectable. It probably isn't exactly what you want, but I'm not sure. Check out the docs (or just download it and test it on a dev server, it's free anyways) and see if this is right for you.

https://solspace.com/docs/primary_category/control_panel/

Comment: Also worth checking out: https://github.com/AboutWout/lonely_cat.ee2_addon